# sequelize-typescirpt many-to-many relation between 2 enitities of the same model

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to implement a many-to-many relation between users.

I've created the following models

```
@Table({ updatedAt: false })
export class User extends Model<Partial<User>> {
    @Unique
    @Column
    name?: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => Follows, "followsId", "userId")
    followers?: User[];

    @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => Follows, "userId", "followsId")
    follows?: User[];

    @CreatedAt
    @Column
    createdAt!: Date;

    @UpdatedAt
    @Column
    updatedAt!: Date;
}


@Table({ updatedAt: false })
export class Follows extends Model<Partial<Follows>> {
    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column
    userId!: number;

    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column
    followsId!: number;
}
```

When I try to follow user 3 and 2 from user 1, I should get the following rows in the follows tabe:
{userId: 1, follows: 2}
{userId: 1, follows: 3}
But I am getting a `unique violation` error, because userId seems to have to be unique.

How do I correctly implement this relation and how can I access all the users a user follows and all the followers of a user?